# pass commands with spaces as function arguments

Tags: bash, function

I have a function that checks the exit status of the previous command and should run multiple commands if it isn't 0 (success)

```
revert()
{
if [ $? -ne 0 ]
then
  echo $#
  for c in $@
  do
    Execute command contained in passed string
  done
  echo "Operation failed. Reverting..."
  exit 1
fi
}
```

I try to call this function and I get this output:

```
revert "ls" "ls -la"
2
ls ls -la
auten.py  canReach.sh  chpass.sh  newUser.sh  popo  secdir.sh
auten.py  canReach.sh  chpass.sh  newUser.sh  popo  secdir.sh
No command '-la' found, did you mean:
 Command 'tla' from package 'tla' (universe)
-la: command not found
```

Obviously the space is the problem, and I tried number of solutions on this page but all I got is the same output and one HUGE HEADACHE.
So before responding, please try my function and see if you can get the desired output. Thank you.

Comment: what if one of the commands is actually supposed to contain a space?  maybe you want some meta-syntax like `find` does for commands: `revert ls \; ls -la`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `"$@"` with quotes, and then execute the command with `eval "$c"`.

```
revert()
{
    (( $? == 0 )) && return 0

    for c in "$@"
    do
        eval "$c"
    done

    echo "Operation failed. Reverting..." >&2
    exit 1
}
```

You can read `x && y` as "if x then y". It's a common scripting shorthand. That first line is equivalent to:

```
if (( $? == 0 )); then return 0; fi
```

Comment: thanks, that was quick and very clear. Could you please explain this `(( $? )) || return 0` line? Seems like an OR..